# Azure Webjob keeps on being deleted

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I've created a WebJob to send email for my web site.  The job is on a 5 minute schedule.

The job ran for a day with no issues and then started reporting:

Http Action - Response from host ': 'NotFound' Response Headers: Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache.

I didn't delete the job but it's no longer there in the webjobs area of the website dashboard.  Is anyone else experiencing this and does anyone have an idea of what is happening?

Comment: Did you redeploy the website or did any other changes?

Comment: I did publish the web site.  I also changed the schedule.  When I publish the site do I need t republish the jobs?

Comment: How did you publish the site? you need to make sure the publish process will not delete App_Data directory (if you used VS/webdeploy there is a setting for it).

Comment: @Amit - do you mean I need to check the "exclude files from the App_Data folder" check box? It's currently unchecked

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and finally found resolution.

What was occurring for my particular case was I was deploying from Git and unbeknownst to me it was erasing my WebJob. The key to remember is a WebJob is content that gets deployed from the repo.

Each time I sent up a free commit, it erased my WebJob.

You should add your WebJob to your deployment source code.

This is answered in more detail here: [How to prevent Azure webjobs from being swapped in Azure website production <--> staging slots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31064071/how-to-prevent-azure-webjobs-from-being-swapped-in-azure-website-production#answer-31079730)