# azure webjob does not stop (keeps working after stopping has been requested)

Tags: azure-webjobs, timer-trigger

We have the following situation.

We decided to use webjob in one of our Web App to perform some work every 30 seconds.

For this purpose we use the following code that is called from Main function:

```
        static void Run(bool locally)
    {
        JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
        if (locally)
        {
            config.Tracing.ConsoleLevel = TraceLevel.Verbose;
            config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
        }config.UseTimers();
        JobHost host = new JobHost(config);
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
```

We only have method in the webjob that is triggered by timer:

```
      public static async Task TimerJob([TimerTrigger("00:00:30")] TimerInfo timer)
    {....

     IEnumerable<IInvitationProcessor> processors = _container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IInvitationProcessor>>();

     ....

   }
```

where _container - autofac container

We noticed 2 strange different things(It looks that they are linked):

1) If we stop the webjob using th portal the webjob is dispalyed as Stopped but in fact it keeps working - we see logs in the Log on the portal and also logs in the AppInsights that our webjob code writes to. Restarting of the WebApp does not help. The only

way to stop it is to Delete the webjob(in fact it keeps working) and then restart the WebApp. Only after that the webjob is stopped(In fact it disappears ).

P.S.: Our webjob uses TimerTrigger that in its turn uses distributed lock to garantee that only one instance of the wbjob will be called(every 30 seconds). So the locally  started instance manages to acquire the lock only after the above actions(Deletion adn restart) hav been performed. - just another evidence
that "deleted\stopped" webjob keeps running.

2) After some time(perhaps after redeploy) our webjob starts raising the following exception

System.IO.FileNotFoundException handled at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate

while trying to resolve the dependencies(it looks very strange because most of the time all the dependecies are resolved successfully - while deployed on the azure Web App or locally)

thanks

Comment: It's quite strange that it would still be running after stopping it. How many instances is your Web App scaled out to? And if you look at Process Explorer in the Azure Portal, do you still see the WebJob process after stopping it?

Comment: Hi, we only have one instance of the WebApp that contains webjob. We are just developing our application so there is not any serious load.

Comment: About Process Explorer, yesterday I reinstalled all the WebApps on our envs so at the moment if I stop the webjob I do not see the logs - sounds good(But I am sure the problem will occure soon). The process w3wp(the one related to the WebJob) does not contain Arrow\cmd\<AssemblyName> any more. I will provide you more information about about ProcessExpolrer when the error repeates  again. By the way we have this problem only with the webjob that uses TimerTrigger (on different envs).

Comment: Ok, if you hit it again, hopefully we can get more info.

Comment: Are you using staging slots? I've seen cases like this where people didn't realize they had jobs running in a slot. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31064071/how-to-prevent-azure-webjobs-from-being-swapped-in-azure-website-production).

Comment: Hi, no, we do not use them at the moment

Comment: Does it reproduce again after reinstalled all the webApps?

Comment: @TomSun-MSFT We did reproduce that today - with same issue - Autofac & FileNot found exception.

Comment: Hi, Yes it reproduced today on 2 envs. I opened one of the envs' Prcess Explorer and saw strange thing:

Comment: There is 2 "w3wp" processes, one for web site(I suspect) and one for webjob. Yesterday there was only one "subprocess" for webjob(after click on the black arrow) but now I see 2! They have different PID, different location, but the same InstanceID

Comment: ID: 33200
File path:D:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\AsyncOperationsController\kqy1wuf3.ir3\Uptick.IdentityService.AsyncOperationsController.exe
Instance ID: 561577

[5:30]  
ID: 17396
File path:D:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\AsyncOperationsController\czibdsdy.xca\Uptick.IdentityService.AsyncOperationsController.exe
Instance ID: 561577

Comment: I decided not to delete\stop webjobs until you tell me something. But I pretty sure that after I stop the webjob one of that sub processes will stay alive. Thanks a lot

Comment: I am not sure it's important or not, but we use several webjobs in several web apps and we only have such problem with this webjob that uses timertrigger to invoke method every 30 seconds.

Comment: @TomSun-MSFT could you comment our observations?

Comment: I noticed the same problem today. The web job shows as stopped in Azure Portal but it is still running. When I go to the Kudu web job log it shows also as stopped but when I show the log details I can see that it is still running every minute. @TomSun-MSFT is this a known issue? What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: I noticed the same problem today with a QueueTrigger. I deleted the webjob in the portal, I even checked the publish folder --> it was empty but when I run the webjob locally connecting to the same queue I noticed some queue messages where still processed using the 'old' code. Using the Process Explorer I see my 'deleted' webjob was still running. After killing it, it finally stopped.