# Would swapping slots have any impact on long running jobs?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment-slots

There's a .NET Core web-app running on Azure App Service. It has two slots, a production slot, and a staging slot.

The web app sometimes process's a big request which takes 1-3 minutes to finish.

If I swap the production and staging slots while the long-running task is ongoing, would it stop the task from finishing ?

Answer (score 2):

> If I swap the production and staging slots while the long-running task is ongoing, would it stop the task from finishing ?

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots):

> The instances in your former production instances (those that will be swapped into staging after this swap operation) will be recycled quickly in the last step of the swap process. In case you have any **long running operations** in your application, **they will be abandoned**, when the workers recycle. This also applies to function apps. Therefore your application code should be written in a fault tolerant way.

Reference: [How to prevent Azure webjobs from being swapped in Azure website production <--> staging slots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31064071/how-to-prevent-azure-webjobs-from-being-swapped-in-azure-website-production)